# Google datastore performance: 2 gets vs 1 filter query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Using the GAE datastore, what option below would perform the best? (Assume that memcache is not available)

Option 1:
DataModel: Entity User has some key, and an email address (the email can't be used as the key)

a) Perform a query on User that filters for a match by email

OR Option 2:

DataModel: Entity User has some key, Entity UserLogin has email address as key, and user key

a) Perform a get on UserLogin, then 
b) Perform a get on User using the user key from UserLogin

Comment: I'd go with Option 2 if you use Objectify or NDB - memcache will make it really speedy in some cases, and it will be easier to make sure email addresses are unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get operations are substantially faster than queries, not to mention cheaper to execute. The sequence of two get operations is likely to be faster than a single query. For example, on the status dashboard, a [get operation](http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/datastore/2012/11/08#ae-trust-detail-datastore-get-latency) hovers at around 10 milliseconds, while a [query operation](http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/datastore/2012/11/08#ae-trust-detail-datastore-query-latency) hovers at around 80 milliseconds - but if this matters to you, I would encourage you to benchmark both and verify for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that option 1 will be faster, because in option 2 you perform one operation, get the result, and only after that perform the second operation.

The difference, however, is negligible, unless you do it at least a few million times each day.